# Using openbox to autostart GUI application Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, archlinux

I'm trying to use openbox to customize my raspberry pi 3. Basically, what I want to do is start an openbox session on boot up and have openbox autostart a GUI application. This is what I have so far

in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

I commented out the first 3 lines:

```
#@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
#@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

and added this line:

```
@openbox-session
```

This causes openbox to start when I boot up my system. I see a black screen

Following this guide: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart It says that

"When you log in with the "Openbox" session type, or launch Openbox with the openbox-session command, the environment script will be executed to set up your environment, and the autostart script can launch any applications you want to run at startup."

so, I edited the autostart file in ~/.config/openbox/autostart in my pi user. (I also tried editing the global file) I put this in the file:

```
/home/pi/mystartupprogram
```

On first reboot it worked my GUI starts up which is great but...next reboot I'm back to black screen and I see part of my GUI in the top left corner and all the rest is black.

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this?  I'm researching the most light-weight possible way to create a kiosk that will show a web page with possible image transitions (dakboard.com specifically).  I would like to use a Pi Zero W so it's gotta be REALLY light.  I wish someone had an opengl or framebuffer driven browser that could run from the GPU from the terminal (graphical - not lynx)

Answer (score 5):

This is the simple answer: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`
One can just run this and select the openbox-session then the next restart will get you the openbox window manager.
No need for hacking files etc.

Comment: Can you edit and expand upon your answer, else it may be deleted. Stack Exchange is looking for comprehensive answers.

Comment: This answer doesn't need any more explaination this is the best way to switch to an alternative window manager on a raspberry pi

Comment: This is the right answer: if the OP will ever want to go back to lxsession, or have to reconfigure a system after reinstalling it, doing manual changes in a bunch of config files will take lots of time.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, restarting the display manager should be sufficient. `sudo systemctl restart display-manager.service`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I post it for any future googlers.

---

1. ### Disable Desktop autologin

   Run `sudo raspi-config` and navigate to `3 Boot Options` / `B1 Desktop / Cli`and choose `B2 Console Autologin`
2. ### Run `startx` in `rc.local`

   Open `rc.local` with `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`. At the end, before `exit 0` add `startx &`
3. ### Configure `xinitrc`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
   ```

   Comment this line

   ```
   . /etc/X11/xsession
   ```

   Add this line to start openbox

   ```
   exec openbox-session
   ```
4. ### Run your programs with `autostart`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart
   ```

   Add your commands

   ```
   /path/to/program &
   ```

   **Important:** End all commands with `&`

---

Voilà, you have now an Raspberry Pi that automatically boots to Openbox and autostarts your applications

Comment: Worked perfect, but I've used the following part in `~/.bash_profile`: `[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && startx` (instead of the `rc.local` part)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=284516#p1722227) to be useful

install the rpi lite version then:
`sudo apt install lightdm openbox`
lightdm = login manager, just use raspi-config to select autologin gui
openbox = gui to run your app

you can use a tty for command line to setup your app to auto start:
example:
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
nano ~/.config/autostart/my_app.desktop

in nano:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/my/app <-best to use full path ex: /home/pi/bin/my_app